# Understanding bra-ket notation as in quantum computer in terms of pure algebra

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, notation

Since I'm not a Physics student, but a Mathematics student, the only physics course I went through is elementary physics (일반물리학, textbook by Jearl Walker, David Halliday, and Robert Resnick). Not even Classical Mechanics.

Yet, I've been interested in quantum computing, and my professor (who is an expert in Analysis and Image Processing) recommended me a book, Practical Quantum Computing for Developers by Vladimir Silva.

As a consequence, I had to understand bra-ket notation. Past glances (Wikipedia, Youtube videos, and [applets by Paul Falstad](http://falstad.com/mathphysics.html)) to Quantum Mechanics didn't much help, yet other questions here were helpful.

As far as I understand:

- Kets are unit vectors in a function space (whose dimension is uncountably infinite).
- Kets' entries are complex numbers.
- $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ are orthogonal.
- $|0\rangle$ has lower energy than $|1\rangle$.
- $a|0\rangle + b|1\rangle$ means a superposition between $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$, where $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$, and where $|a|^2$ and $|b|^2$ represents the probability to which value the superposition will fall when observed.
- $|00\rangle$ is a shorthand for $|0\rangle \otimes |0\rangle$, where $\otimes$ is tensor product.
- When two qubits cannot be represented by $(a|0\rangle + b|1\rangle) \otimes (c|0\rangle + d|1\rangle)$, they are entangled.
- Bras are covectors in the dual space.
- Operators map kets to kets (or bras to bras) and is a unitary matrix.

My questions are:

- Are $-|0\rangle$, $i|0\rangle$, $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}|0\rangle$ valid (that is, physically possible) kets? How are they different from $|0\rangle$?
- Do $|00\rangle$, $|01\rangle$, $|10\rangle$, and $|11\rangle$ from an orthogonal basis?
- This [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/g_IaVepNDT4) by Veritasium states $|00\rangle$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|01\rangle - |10\rangle)$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|01\rangle + |10\rangle)$, and $|11\rangle$ as the fundamental orthogonal basis for two qubits. Why are they fundamental? How is this derived? What makes the energies of the middle two states different?
- For $a|00\rangle + b|01\rangle + c|10\rangle + d|11\rangle$, does every combination of $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ as long as $|a|^2 + |b|^2 + |c|^2 + |d|^2 = 1$ represent a valid ket?

Just in case, here are the math courses I've gone through:

> Calculus, Analysis, Linear Algebra, Set Theory, Differential Equations (Ordinary and Partial), Multivariable Calculus, Discrete Mathematics, Geometry (Euclidean and Hyperbolic), Probability Theory, Number Theory, Complex Analysis, Abstract Algebra, Topology, Statistics, Graph Theory, Differential Geometry, Numerical Analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are $-|0\rangle$, $i|0\rangle$, $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}|0\rangle$ valid (that is, physically possible) kets? How are they different from $|0\rangle$?

Yes, they are valid, but describe the same physical state. A state can be characterized by its expectation values, and a phase factor $e^{i\varphi}$ cancels with the complex-conjugate factor from the bra.

Technically, (pure) quantum states don't live in the Hilbert space, but its projective space.

Note that such phase factors do matter when superposing states: While $+|1\rangle$ and $-|1\rangle$ describe the same state,
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle)
$$
do not.

> Do $|00\rangle$, $|01\rangle$, $|10\rangle$, and $|11\rangle$ from an orthogonal basis?

Yes.

> This [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/g_IaVepNDT4) by Veritasium states $|00\rangle$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|01\rangle - |10\rangle)$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|01\rangle + |10\rangle)$, and $|11\rangle$ as the fundamental orthogonal basis for two qubits. Why are they fundamental? How is this derived? What makes the energies of the middle two states different?

Didn't watch the video, but the states have well-defined symmetry properties (the state with the minus sign is antisymmetric, all others are symmetric). The energies of the states depend on the Hamiltonian, and I can't think of anything relevant to say about the generic case off-hand. Maybe assume a simple Hamiltonian
$$
H = \begin{pmatrix}E_0 & 0 \\ 0 & E_1\end{pmatrix}
$$
and see what happens?

> For $a|00\rangle + b|01\rangle + c|10\rangle + d|11\rangle$, does every combination of $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ as long as $|a|^2 + |b|^2 + |c|^2 + |d|^2 = 1$ represent a valid ket?

Yes. However, kets that differ only by a global phase factor will describe the same physical state (see above).